# Why does -1 < s.length() returns false but 0 < s.length() returns true in C++

Tags: c++, string

```
string s = "abc";
int i = -1;
cout<<(i < s.length());
```

It returns false in this case. Why?

But when I write

```
string s = "abc";
int i = 0;
cout<<(i < s.length());
```

It returns true

Comment: Did you enable compiler warnings? If not, please do so and carefully read the warning message printed for the first snippet. I get `warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type' {aka 'long unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]`

Comment: `s.length()` returns an unsigned integer and you are trying to compare it with a signed integer.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you are comparing a int and a size_t, as  Botje and Jana Doe pointed out. The solution is as ChrisMM pointed out:

> i should be defined as size_t, as opposed to int.

Comment: Converting `size_t` to `int` is generally a bad idea....

Comment: I see your argument, but I also think the solution needs to fit the application. I think this would give problems if the string is longer then  2,147,483,647 characters and that should be well in the range in this case, but if I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should stick to the signed-ness / type of the function. It's a better habit to be in. `i` should be defined as `size_t`, as opposed to `int`. Firstly, it's unsigned, secondly, `size_t` (and the return type of `length()`) changes based on x86 or x86-64.

Comment: Ok a well made argument, I will change the answer.